# Creating SQL Connection in Excel that creates and drops temporary tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, temp-tables, data-connections

I've created query that runs perfectly in Microsoft SQL Server and it utilizes temporary tables it creates and drops. I now want to create a data connection in Microsoft Excel that will run my query and display the results in Excel, so that business partners who do not know SQL can utilize the report.

However, when I try to run the query in a data connection in excel I get errors like the following:
"Database name 'database' ignored, referencing object in tempdb."

OR

"The query did not run, or the database table could not be opened. Check the database server or contact your database administrator. Make sure the external database is available and hasn't been moved or reorganized, then try the operation again."

I then tried to use the phrase "SET NOCOUNT on" before creating my temporary tables but it did not resolve the issue and I still have no report.

Here is how my code is set up

```
        select
        x.PRODUCT_ID,
        y.SETID,
        LW = ISNULL (SUM(y.SALES_QTY) ,0)  
        INTO database.#tmpLastWeek
        --#tempLastWeek is a temporary table I am creating here and inserting values into
        from 
        database.sales_table y
        inner join
        database.product_table x
        on y.PRODUCT_ID = x.PRODUCT_ID
        and x.SETID = y.SETID
        where 
        y.stores IN (
        'storeslist'
        )
        and y.sales_week = @this_week - 1
        and y.sales_year = @this_year
        group by 
        x.PRODUCT_ID,
        y.SETID,
        x.DESCR
```

Then I select from the temporary table #tmpLastWeek

```
    select * from #tmpLastWeek
```

Then finally I drop this temporary table so that it can be ran again

```
    drop table #tmpLastWeek
```

Any advice or suggestions on getting this query to be ran thru and SQL connection in Excel would be much appreciated! Thanks!!!!

Comment: Could you not look at wrapping it all up into a stored proc and calling the stored proc instead? Also, reference your temp table just as #tmpLastWeek.

Comment: I'm not one of the DBAs, so I cannot do that without their permission. That is a last resort option

Comment: Why not do away with your temporary table altogether and just run your query from excel. As I'm not sure what advantages the temporary table is giving you.

Comment: @SteveFord makes a good point, what is the temp table used for?

Comment: This is just a small piece of the total query. The total query is much larger and the alternative to creating temporary tables is utilizing nested/subqueries. But that option really slows down the process to about 4 minutes which is entirely too long. Using the temporary tables reduces my run time to less than 1 minute

Comment: I also removed  the database prefix before creating the temp table so now the line reads   "INTO #tmpLastWeek" but that also did not solve the problem

Comment: Can you update your question with the exact errors you receive and how you are making the connection from Excel to SQL Server?

Comment: Done. Updated with the latest error after removing the database prefix before creating the temp table

Comment: Can you not use a table variable with Insert ... Select?

Comment: A table variable is a new concept for me. I am looking into that now? Do you have any suggestions for how to implement this in my query above?

Comment: I tried to use a table variable in the following way:                          Declare @tmpLastWeek TABLE(
 [PRODUCT_ID] [char](18) NOT NULL,
 [SETID] [char](5) NOT NULL,
 [LW] [INT] NOT NULL
 
);                                                                                                                       Insert into tmpLastWeek                                                                            select ...                                                                                                        select * from tmpLastWeek

Comment: I tried to use a table variable in the following way:                          Declare @tmpLastWeek TABLE(
 [PRODUCT_ID] [char](18) NOT NULL,
 [SETID] [char](5) NOT NULL,
 [LW] [INT] NOT NULL
 
);                                                                                                                       Then inserting into it and selecting * from it, but I got the same error in excel. It again worked SQL server, but excel can't handle it for some reason